# Deserializing JSON to Object 

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I'm receiving JSON, that i need to Deserialize. I'm using JavaScriptSerializer to do so.
E.g. Objects

```
class Player
    {
        public string name{ set; get; }
        public float yPos { set; get; }
        public float xPos { set; get; }
    }

class Communication
    {
        public string id{ set; get; }
        public string message{ set; get; }
        public string status{ set; get; }
    }
```

E.g. JSONs:

```
var json1 = "[{\"name\":\"Master\",\"xPos\":\"34.67\",\"yPos\":\"85.36\"}, {\"name\":\"Puppet\",\"xPos\":\"19.56\",\"yPos\":\"75.19\"}]";

var json2 = "[{\"id\":\"5697862\",\"message\":\"Hello\",\"status\":\"85.36\"}, {\"id\":\"4698458\",\"message\":\"Hi\",\"status\":\"75.19\"}]";
```

Deserializer Method:

```
private static List<T> Deserialize<T>(string json)
        {
            var s = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<T> obj = s.Deserialize<List<T>>(json);
            return obj;
        }
```

But here is the problem I have two different kind of JSON messages coming. So how do I figure out to what object I need to  Deserialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of deserializing to a specific class you can process the result dynamically

```
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic dynObj =  js.DeserializeObject(jsonN);
foreach (var obj in dynObj)
{
    if (obj.ContainsKey("name")) Console.WriteLine(obj["name"]);
    else Console.WriteLine(obj["message"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a look at the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) (which can also deserialize). This class ensures that you are following the specific contract when you serialize and deserialize to and from JSON, respectively.

For deserialization, it works something like this:

```
stream1.Position = 0;
Person p2 = (Person)ser.ReadObject(stream1);
```

Serialization works like this:

```
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
ser.WriteObject(stream1, p);
```

See the link for additional explanation.

Comment: Good point! Anyway, I answered OP with another approach, because who knows which .NET version is using and who knows if he can use `DataContractJsonSerializer`...

Comment: Maybe you'd point that `Person` or any serializable class should mark the class and its propierties with appropiate attributes in order to let this work.

Comment: How does it help figuring out which JSON I have received? I still would have the same problem deciding to deserialize to Person  or Media for example.